# Broken ruby on Mac when dealing with cocoapods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to install a Cocoapods plugin and my Mac's gem and Ruby seem completely broken.

Here's my output for 'pod install':

```
[project] pod install                                                                                          master  ✗ ✭
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gemspec:17.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/i18n-0.9.5.gemspec:17.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/escape-0.0.4.gemspec:18.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/coffee-script-source-1.11.1.gemspec:16.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/em-websocket-0.5.1.gemspec:15.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/specifications/nokogiri-1.5.6.gemspec:22.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/rouge-2.2.1.gemspec:18.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/sass-3.7.4.gemspec:21.
clang: error: no such file or directory: '10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin18'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include'

---------------------------------------------
Error loading the plugin `cocoapods-keys-2.2.0`.

CompilationError - error executing "xcrun clang -dynamic -bundle  -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress   -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS -L. -I /Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I /Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin18 -I /Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib -o \"/Users/bhavin/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.3.0/Inline_OSXKeychain_5b2f8d1cd1bde9c4ff3fea49f09cd5c1.bundle\" \"/Users/bhavin/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.3.0/Inline_OSXKeychain_5b2f8d1cd1bde9c4ff3fea49f09cd5c1.c\" -lc -framework Security -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices ": pid 8209 exit 1
Renamed /Users/bhavin/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.3.0/Inline_OSXKeychain_5b2f8d1cd1bde9c4ff3fea49f09cd5c1.c to /Users/bhavin/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.3.0/Inline_OSXKeychain_5b2f8d1cd1bde9c4ff3fea49f09cd5c1.c.bad
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.5/lib/inline.rb:621:in `build'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.5/lib/inline.rb:859:in `inline'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/osx_keychain-1.0.2/lib/osx_keychain.rb:17:in `<class:OSXKeychain>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/osx_keychain-1.0.2/lib/osx_keychain.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-keys-2.2.0/lib/keyring.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-keys-2.2.0/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:94:in `block in safe_activate_and_require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:94:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:94:in `safe_activate_and_require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
---------------------------------------------

[!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-keys` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.
```

I have installed cocoapods-keys with 'sudo gem install cocoapods-keys', but I have no idea why my pod install is turning up all these errors. I'm tempted to remove my system Ruby and start over, but it seems from other answers like that's a bad idea.

Can someone help?

Comment: It looks like a path here has a space in it that's confusing whatever setup you have. `10.app` seems like the end of something like `Xcode 10.app`.

Comment: Makes sense! I removed Xcode 10 and I'm reinstalling it. How do I reset my ruby setup?

Comment: Anytime I run a gem command, I get a permissions error - ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0 directory.

Comment: I'm also just trying to uninstall the cocoapods gem, but I keep getting the error that I don't have write access for /usr/bin.