# How to fix a broken System Ruby installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

My Mac system Ruby installation is completely broken.

I've seen several posts recommending me to set up RVM or rbenv but I'm trying to install an Xcode pod (cocoapods), and I have no idea why my system Ruby is so broken.

When I run `gem`, I get the following output:

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/coffee-script-source-1.11.1.gemspec:16.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/em-websocket-0.5.1.gemspec:15.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/escape-0.0.4.gemspec:18.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gemspec:17.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/i18n-0.9.5.gemspec:17.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/specifications/nokogiri-1.5.6.gemspec:22.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/rouge-2.2.1.gemspec:18.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/specifications/sass-3.7.4.gemspec:21.
RubyGems is a sophisticated package manager for Ruby.  This is a
basic help message containing pointers to more information.
```

and it seems that these are just deprecation warnings, and, from some other posts, that the answer is to simply run `gem pristine --all --no-extensions`.

When I run essentially any `gem` command, I get a permissions error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

How do I reset my system Ruby? I don't use Ruby and I had run the command `gem install cocoapods` yesterday. Since then it's been unusable.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/61148892/128421. Don't duplicate questions as they'll be closed quickly. If you didn't get a usable solution to the previous one then you need to be more detailed in the description of the steps you followed that broke the system. Have you followed any recommendations previously given to you?

Comment: "I have no idea why my system Ruby is so broken." So you're saying this happened magically, that it worked previously and then quit working without any action on your part? What directions did you follow when installing cocopods?

Answer (score 0):

Note that basically you should install Ruby by yourself with tools like `rbenv`, but if you don't want to do it, please refer to the answer below.

---

System Ruby is installed for `root`, so you need `sudo` command to interact with it.
Try `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

(Btw, `gem` command with no sub commands just shows the usage, which is not *broken*)

Comment: Don't alter the system Ruby, and especially don't use `sudo` when you don't know what it does and will do when used. Apple installs it for their system use; We can run scripts with it, but modifying/updating/deleting gems or updating the version can break Apple's code using it so it's better to, instead, use of one the several sandbox managers for Ruby. `gem` will still work if the system Ruby is intact, but the reported error suggests it's not working at all.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the comment. I updated the answer to point out that we should install Ruby with `rbenv` or such tools.

Comment: Thanks, but it's no necessary to tell us you changed anything. We can see what changed and when; SO maintains revision tracking and it's visible to us once we hit a certain number of points.